# Solr q results vs database sql results

Tags: configuration, solr

I am trying to configure solr to index an oracle database. I have enable leading wildcard searches and various other filters as such in my schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true"
       maxPosAsterisk="3" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I have indexed all searchable column in the database and use the same names as column names for solr fields and hence my select query in the db-data-config.xml is simply a select * from view ;

We are receiving different results from solr and database queries

for example an sql query as below returns 1307 records

```
select count(*) from VIEW 
where (COLUMN1 = 'Value0' and COLUMN2='Value1') 
OR COLUMN3 in ('Value2','Value3','Value4') 
AND COLUMN4='Value5'
```

and a solr query as below returns only 7

```
  (COLUMN1:(Value0) AND COLUMN2:(Value1)) 
  OR (COLUMN3:(Value2 OR Value3 OR Value4))
  AND (COLUMN4:(Value5))
```

We are operating on only 1 view which has all the relevant data. The solr configurations index to all columns in the view and I would have thought that the results would be similar. Can someone kindly explain the discrepancy ?

EDIT

Adding values as asked : solr query

```
COUNTRY_NAME:(United States) AND ELEMENT_CODE:(CT)) OR (UNIT_STATUS:(Operating OR Order OR Shipped)) AND (FRAME_GR_DISPLAY:(06A))
```

database query

```
select * from VIEW where 
(COUNTRY_NAME = 'United States' AND ELEMENT_CODE='CT')
 OR  UNIT_STATUS in ('Operating','Order','Shipped') 
   AND FRAME_GR_DISPLAY='06A'
```

Comment: there's a typo, says `Valu0` instead of `Value0`

Comment: What are the actual values? Are they really 'value0', 'value1', etc?

Comment: err no..the actual values are string type pertaining to the column .. for example country would be united states and so on ...

Comment: i was expecting the results to be similar, on OR operations and larger queries the results differ vastly but if i were to take short queries for both sql and solr say condition AND condition2 OR condition3 the results differ by around 10. Should i be expecting them to be similar ?

Comment: please post the actual values, they're relevant to the question.

Comment: i have added the actual values to the question

Comment: Ideally, highlight one of the mismatches. If you only get 7 back from Solr, it should be easy to find another that didn't come back out of the 1300.

Comment: do you have the same number of **total** documents in Solr as in the relational database?

Comment: yes i do, i checked that out. a total of 23k+ for both, the exact same number.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking if you want verbatim matches like SQL does, you should not use an analyzed field type. For example, in the default schema the `string` field type (class solr.StrField) is unanalyzed.

If you get lost in analysis filters and tokenizers and don't quite understand what's going on, try using debugQuery=on in your Solr querystring or use the [Solr analysis tool](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/j-solr2/).

Comment: But i want to enable leading wildcard queries that would require me to have an analyzed field type by design ..

Comment: @sunny Are you sure you want leading wildcards and not just the right tokenizer? What kind of queries (concretely) do you need? There are no leading wildcard queries in the examples you mentioned so far.

Comment: I mean i will be using leading wildcard queries so i have configured my solrfield , text, appropriately. Our end users would be using phrases like contains with , ends with , which i have mapped to the appropriate solr leading wild card queries and is working fine.  We would be enabling search using all boolean operators, text searches like greater than, less than, contains, begins with ..etc..